# Como sumar filas iguales estableciendo una condición

Tags: r

Necesito sumar los créditos en leche para cada individuo (en total son 3 en este ejemplo) pero la suma se debe de realizar hasta antes de que la edad al parto del individuo sea igual o mayor a 85. Por ejemplo para el individuo 1 y 2 no hay problema se pueden sumar todos los créditos, el problema es en el individuo 3, porque cuando la edad al parto es igual o mayor a 85 la suma se debe realizar desde que el individuo tiene 24.6 meses hasta 83.2 meses, no se debe incluir en la suma el crédito cuando la edad del individuo sea 94.3

Pensé en utilizar estos comando, pero no puedo combinar ambas acciones.

```
edadp$id2 <- as.factor(edadp$id2)

mim84 <- tapply(X = edadp$dimmaj,INDEX = edadp$id2,FUN = sum)
```

Lo malo que las funciones anteriores me suma todos los créditos en todas las edades por animal.

Espero me haya dado a entender y sus sugerencias, gracias.

Este es un ejemplo de mi dataframe:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon el dataframe _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes, y de hecho, tu imagen es casi imposible de ver en el modo oscuro. Por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Oh una disculpa, la verdad es la primera vez que inserto imágenes y no sabía que se veía con fondo negro, en mi mensaje se ve blanco y nítido por eso pensé que así se veía para todos. Gracias por tus comentarios.

Answer (score 1):

De partida, pensando en que el problema sea replicable por parte de la comunidad debes compartir un porción de tu dataframe (`dput()` te ayuda para ello) o crear un set de datos reproducibles, como el siguiente:

```
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(id = rep(paste0('Holmex',
                                 1:3),
                          times = 5),
                 edp = rep(seq(20,
                               90,
                               length.out = 5),
                           times = 3) +
                   round(rnorm(15,
                               sd = 5),
                         2),
                 creditos = rep(10,
                                times = 15) +
                   round(rnorm(15,
                               sd = 3),
                         1))

df
#         id   edp creditos
# 1  Holmex1 17.20     15.4
# 2  Holmex2 36.35     11.5
# 3  Holmex3 62.79      4.1
# 4  Holmex1 72.85     12.1
# 5  Holmex2 90.65      8.6
# 6  Holmex3 28.58      6.8
# 7  Holmex1 39.80      9.3
# 8  Holmex2 48.67      6.9
# 9  Holmex3 69.07      7.8
# 10 Holmex1 87.77      8.1
# 11 Holmex2 26.12      4.9
# 12 Holmex3 39.30     12.5
# 13 Holmex1 57.00     10.5
# 14 Holmex2 73.05      6.6
# 15 Holmex3 87.22     13.8
```

Tal como lo planteas, el problema se puede resolver fácilmente con los verbos del universo `tydyr`, en específico los de la librería `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(edp >= 24.6 & edp <= 83.2) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(creditosTotal = sum(creditos))


# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   id      creditosTotal
#   <chr>           <dbl>
# 1 Holmex1          31.9
# 2 Holmex2          29.9
# 3 Holmex3          31.2
```

`filter` te permite filtar por la condición de edad; `group_by`, agrupar por individuo; y `summarise` para obtener estadísticas por los grupos definidos anteriormente.

Comment: Muchas gracias Aldo por tu respuesta, en parte es lo que requiero, pero tengo más de cien mil vacas, para cada una tengo que sumar sus créditos en leche hasta los 84 meses de edad. Y el script que me mandas veo que se tiene que escribir los meses de edad de manera individual. Lo que requiero es lo siguiente: "suma los créditos en leche para cada vaca hasta que la vaca tenga 84 meses de edad". Si tiene más de 84 meses no sumes sus créditos de esas edades. Ojalá me haya dado a entender mejor.

Comment: @sanunso76 no debes escribir nada, la primera parte de mi respuesta es para reproducir el problema. La segunda parte (desde `library(dplyr)`) es la que aplica a tu código

Comment: O sea que puedo modificar en filter y ponerle así: (edp <=84) para que me sume desde la edad más jóven hasta cuando cumpla lo más cercano a los 84 meses? disculpa mi insistencia, solo quiero que me quede claro el concepto.

Comment: Así es, es igual o menor que 84. Si quieres que sea lo más cercano a 84 sin que llegue a esa valor utiliza `< 84`

Comment: Te agradezco por tus comentarios, ya me salió lo que quería.